# Got socket error trying to find package english_words at https://pub.dartlang.org

Tags: dart, flutter

Trying to add a package using the package get option on Android Studio. I'm getting the following error message:

> " Got socket error trying to find package english_words at
>   https://pub.dartlang.org."

Please how can i resolve this?

Comment: Please add more details about your pubspec.yaml, flutter version, dart version.

Comment: Do you have a proxy configured for Android Studio?

Comment: Flutter version: 0.4.4,   Dart version: 2.0.0-dev.54.0.flutter-46ab040e58.

Comment: @dazza5000 No i havent.

Answer (score 2):

Quoted from Android Studio's doc:

> Android Studio supports HTTP proxy settings so you can run Android Studio behind a firewall or secure network.

You need to fix the Proxy Settings in Android Studio. From Android Studio's Documentation Site, I am Sharing the process.

- From the menu bar, click **File > Settings** (on a Mac, click Android Studio > Preferences).
- In the left pane, click **Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > HTTP Proxy.** The HTTP Proxy page appears.
- Select **Auto-detect proxy** settings to use an automatic proxy configuration URL for the proxy settings or **Manual proxy** configuration to enter each of the settings yourself.

  - Click Apply or OK for your changes to take effect.

I hope it helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Like @SouravOni's answer suggests, this is definitely a network issue. The Dartlang server obviously has issues with restricting certain countries.

The fastest way to solve this is by connecting via a VPN. In my case, I use a Kaspersky Antivirus that comes with a VPN , all I had to do was change my location to United Kingdom and then it works

One way to test if this is a connection issue that needs VPN is to visit pub.dartlang.org, if it doesn't go through, then try a VPN