# Waiting for another flutter command to release the startup lock ; Got socket error trying to find package english_words at https://pub.dartlang.org

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I have trying to install flutter onto my Mac.I have realised that I might have installed flutter multiple time without uninstalling properly. Now suggest me the needful to get why flutter fired up and running.

For this error:
Waiting for another flutter command to release the startup lock
I tried running killall -9 dart and removing /bin/cache/lockfile (there was no lock file)
[Waiting for another flutter command to release the startup lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51679269/waiting-for-another-flutter-command-to-release-the-startup-lock)

For this error:
Got socket error trying to find package english_words at https://pub.dartlang.org
I tired changing to auto-detect proxy in android studio
[Got socket error trying to find package english_words at https://pub.dartlang.org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51314315/got-socket-error-trying-to-find-package-english-words-at-https-pub-dartlang-or)

Ps: I followed the flutter docs from the website and not sure what I might have done wrong.

Answer (score 0):

So I found out the answer myself. Just posting the answer so that someone else could benefit.
It was the antivirus in my case. it was not allowing to find the package in  https://pub.dartlang.org.

I turned off the antivirus, now I the flutter runs fine.